# Bold text does not appear as bold font issue on OSX?

Tags: discussion, bug

Sorry if this was asked already but bold text doesn't appear as bold on this site for OSX it seems. Some of the other sites like graphicdesign.stackexchange work fine with bold text.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know; I haven't heard this before.  If you provide more details on your browser version and exactly what you're observing I could try to get the CM team to investigate it.  If it's a multi-SE-site issue this would be much better asked on [Meta.SE].

Comment: It's strange that you don't have this issue on Graphic Design. A similar problem was reported on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307120/323179) but I'm not sure it's the same issue.